# Exit Ruby On Rails controller method from helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

Let's imagine I have a class

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AuthenticatorHelper

  def test
    authenticate_or_fail!
    puts "If I fail, this should be unreachable"
  end
end
```

and

```
module AuthenticationHelper
  def authenticate_or_fail!
    @user = User.find(params[:token])
    unless @user
      render :json => {code: 401, :err => 'Unauthorized'} and return
    end
  end
end
```

What I want to do is either authenticate or reply with a json msg. However, it will obviously ignore my return statement due to nesting and it will always print my message

> If I fail, this should be unreachable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding the question**

You could extract the call into a `before_filter`/`before_action` (based on the rails version).

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AuthenticatorHelper

  before_action :authenticate_or_fail!

  def test
    puts "If I fail, this should be unreachable"
  end
end
```

Please see [the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) for further details.

Because your helper method renders in case of a failure, rails will prevent the `test` method to be called. You will not need the `and return` part then, which would only have returned from the method anyway and as such was a NoOp.

**Apart from the question but also noteworthy:**

I don't want to point out errors for the sake of it. I just want to prevent the OP from running into a series of bugs later on.

```
 User.find(params[:token])
```

Will raise an exception if no record is found. Because of that, the `unless @user` part will not be evaluated in case of an invalid token. You could use

```
User.find_by(id: params[:token])
```

instead.

Your class which looks like it acts as a controller is named `Test` and inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`. The first is unusual as `TestsController` would be more along the lines of rails and the seconds looks plain wrong. A controller has to inherit from `ApplicationController` (which itself inherits from `ActionController::Base`)

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base` doesn't have a `before_action`

Comment: That is correct @Stefan, that is why I advised to inherit from `ApplicationController` instead. I was put of track by `ActiveRecord::Base` as well but using that in the context displayed must clearly be a mistake, so that I simply assumed that it would have to be fixed as described.